# Creating json object out of ko.observables knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to find this in the documentation.

I want to build a JSON object that I can send via ajax using my ko.observables();.

My view model looks like this, but the issue is that if I change the value of the storeNumber text box to an empty text box. it does not update in the self.searchTest object.

I might be doing this complete wrong, is this the best way to create a json object from my text boxes?  It seems very messy.

```
    function StoresViewModel() {
        // Data
        var self = this;
        self.stores = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.storeNumber = ko.observable();
        self.cityName = ko.observable();
        self.stateName = ko.observable();        



        self.searchTest = {
            "City": self.cityName,
            "State": self.stateName,
            "StoreNumber": self.storeNumber,
        };
```

HTML:

```
  <label for="term">Search by store number:</label>
  <input data-bind="value: storeNumber" id="storenumber" name="storenumber" 
  placeholder="Store Number"/>
  <br /><b>or</b><br />
 Search by city and state:<br />

 <input data-bind="value: cityName" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City"/>
 <select name="state" data-bind="value: stateName">//lots of selects</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create Json Object

```
var jsonObj = ko.toJS(StoresViewModel);
alert(jsonObj);//alerts the object.
```

Note: for this to work on older browsers that have no native JSON serializer (e.g., IE 7 or earlier), you must also reference the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library.

To produce JSON string

```
var jsonString = ko.toJSON(StoresViewModel);
alert(jsonString);//alerts the json String.
```

You can also create json object from json String

```
 var jsonString = ko.toJSON(StoresViewModel);
 alert(jsonString);//alerts the json String.

 var myJsonObj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
 alert(myJsonObj);//alerts the object.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var js = ko.toJS(StoresViewModel);
```

This is the [simplest way](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) of doing it, though you need to include a [JSON stringify library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) in IE 6 + 7.

Alternatively, you can use the [Knockout.js mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), which allows you more flexibility, such as being able to ignore some of the observables on your view model:

```
var mapping = {
    'ignore': ["propertyToIgnore", "alsoIgnoreThis"]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```